# Change a specified value on archive - PS

Tags: powershell

i have this following configurations in archive, to be specific on line 15 i have to change string `"srv-01.address"` file name is `UpdateClient.config`, how can i change this on powershell?

```
<ProviderServers>
    <ProviderServer URL="srv-01.address" IsDefault="False" Port="8092" SecureConnection="False" BindingType="BasicHttpBinding" />
  </ProviderServers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use XPath (which is Case-Sensitive)

```
$search  = "srv-01.address"
$replace = "srv-02.address"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'Path\To\UpdateClient.config' -Raw
$xml.SelectNodes("//ProviderServer[@URL='$search']") | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute('URL', $replace) }
$xml.Save('Path\To\UpdateClient.config')
```

You can also use the Case-Insensitive 'dot' method, but for that to realy work, you didn't show enough of the .config xml file.
What it boils down to is that you should follow the structure all the way from the root element.

```
$search  = "srv-01.address"
$replace = "srv-02.address"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'Path\To\UpdateClient.config' -Raw
$xml.providerservers.providerserver | Where-Object { $_.Url -eq $search } | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute('URL', $replace) }
$xml.Save('Path\To\UpdateClient.config')
```

Both methods will update the file to contain

```
<ProviderServers>
  <ProviderServer URL="srv-02.address" IsDefault="False" Port="8092" SecureConnection="False" BindingType="BasicHttpBinding" />
</ProviderServers>
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is an xml file import it and set the attribute like:

```
$xml = [xml](gc "FILEPATH")
$xml.ProviderServers.ProviderServer.setattribute("URL","UpdateClient.config")
```